# Azure Iothub-Explorer epoch error?

Tags: azure, esp8266, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli, azure-iot-sdk

I'm trying to look at messages that are being sent from my esp8266 module via iothub-explorer but I'm getting the following error.

The command I'm running

```
iothub-explorer monitor-events DeviceID --login "HostName=Something.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=key;SharedAccessKey=asdfsdfsdfasdfsdf="
```

Error

```
Error: At least one receiver for the endpoint is created with epoch of '3', and so non-epoch receiver is not allowed. Either reconnect with a higher epoch, or make sure all epoch receivers are closed or disconnected.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a consumer group for IoT Hub explorer to receive events that sent by esp8266. In Azure Portal you can do it like this:

[image]

Specify the consumer group created above using `--consumer-group` option in your command like this:

```
iothub-explorer monitor-events myFirstDevice --consumer-group ReceiveEsp8266Events --login "HostName=xxxx"
```

Ref: [iothub-explorer-monitor-events.js](https://github.com/Azure/iothub-explorer/blob/master/iothub-explorer-monitor-events.js#L43)